# Want to be intimated if there is change in the value of a particular Collection

Tags: mongodb

Hi i have a collection named "secs" in our Mongo DB

The Records inside secs looks like below way :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c9dbc9f0e2a3f7445a0550"), "active_flag" : "1",  "pcls" : "150.2500",  "pe" : "na" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c9dbc9f0e2a3f7445a0551"), "active_flag" : "1",  "pcls" : "150.2500",  "pe" : "na" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c9dbc9f0e2a3f7445a0552"), "active_flag" : "1",  "pcls" : "150.2500",  "pe" : "na" }
```

// Removed most of the fields to look simple .

```
Is there any way we can write trigger in Mongo DB ??
```

**My Requirement is that if the pcls value is changed or equal to zero , i want to be intimated ??**

Please let me know if this is possible ??

Comment: trigger not present in mongoDB

Comment: Thats related to adding new rows , my question is related to changes in the values of a collection .

Comment: The linked duplicate question applies to collection changes just as well as new rows.

Comment: There are no "rows" in mongoDB. Everything is a document in a collection.